# How to connect VS Code to server without RDP

Tags: ssh, vscode-remote

How to connect VS Code to linux server by not login to remote desktop

Current way I login:
open Personal Computer >> Establish VPN connection >> open RDP and login >> open putty/VS code and open SSH connection (linux) write code

Is there a way I can connect VS Code/Putty (Locally installed in PC) to SSH development box without RDP?
example - Local Personal Computer >> Establish VPN connection >> open putty/VS code (locally installed) to establish/connect SSH development server(linux)

When I try SSH from local machine, it always give - `time out error`.. but with same connection setting (ssh username@servername.companyname.com) if try from remote desktop (work computer) it works fine